# Get parameter and value appended to the extension of .js file

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a site which has a js file included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js?param=value"></script>
```

Is there any way that I can - from inside `script.js` - get the param and its value?

Comment: No. That's not possible using JS alone.

Comment: no you can't get that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Ah, but it is. :-)

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. Although I'd argue your solution is really janky and not something that should really be done in a production environment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: And yet, a lot of people do, including really big organizations. They either embed information in the URL, in `data-*` attributes, or in the content of the `script` tag (which as you know is ignored when there's a `src`). It's reliable. But yes, I prefer other methods.

Comment: After seeing various organisations 'enterprise' code I believe you :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: LOL. Yeah, likewise, seen some very scary stuff... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that script runs *synchronously* with the HTML parser, you can get the last `script` element and read its `src`:

```
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
console.log(script.src); // "script.js?param=value"
```

Then just use string parsing to grab what's after the `?`, break it into name/value pairs, etc.

Or if you use `async` or `defer` on the script element and so it may not be the last one, look for the one whose `src` contains `script.js`:

```
var script = document.querySelector("script[src*=script.js]");
console.log(script.src); // "script.js?param=value"
```

This is a bit less reliable, since scripts can be renamed. You could always just use `querySelectorAll("script")` and find the one with parameters of the sort you expect.

---

For the avoidance of doubt: I don't *recommend* it. I prefer to pass options with an initialization call, or by requiring an object to be defined before the script is added (like Google does), etc. But it can be done.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.